# Building an Entry Level MTB. How should I choose suspension forks?

Tags: fork, suspension

I am new to Mountain Biking. I just bought a CRONUS HOLTS 330 (Hardtail) with Shimano gear system and disk brakes. Its a 19" frame with 26" tyres. All aluminium pretty light weight. The brakes are ok for now the only problem is the suspension forks. The forks are made by zoom and they suck. They dont spring back if they go in I have to jerk the handlebar upwards to bring them back to midway preload position. I am interested in buying a used rockshock air suspension fork but I cant figure out which ones are best for me because there are a million different types out there. Please help.

Comment: On a cheap bike like this, the right thing to do is to sell it and buy a bike with most the desired components on it. The cost of a new (decent) suspension fork and the labor to install it will probably exceed the cost of the bike in most cases, and the remainder of components will often let you down in performance.

Comment: If I had the choice between entry level suspension or rigid, I'd take rigid. You can get pretty nice and light rigid forks for less than 'cheap' suspension forks - are you set on suspension forks?

Comment: According to a comment you bought the bike new.  Why would you buy a new bike that you need to upgrade?  A new suspension fork is expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the sram product matrix can be handy (`y` is cost, `x` is severity of impacts):

[image]

<sub>source: https://www.sram.com/sites/all/themes/sram_2011/st_rockshox/_images/products/product-matrix.png</sub>

Answer (score 0):

First, if you bought the bike new, take it to the shop.  But if you bought it used and it's out of warranty, it should be easy to find a matching fork.  Here are some that look relevant from RockShox now:

- https://www.sram.com/rockshox/products/xc-32-tk
- https://www.sram.com/rockshox/products/sektor-tk
- https://www.sram.com/rockshox/products/recon-gold-r

Anything like those with a 26" wheel size, 1 1/8" steerer, and disc brake mounts should be OK.  You probably want 100mm of travel or so.

It would help if you can tell us the model year of the bike (might be printed on a sticker on the bottom tube), as well as the fork details.

Comment: Its a New Bike, http://neocycle.com.my/harga-ori-mtb/mtb-cronus/20140423_173828/ here is an image. The problem is that the shop where I bought it from knows nothing about it. So I will have to customise it on my own. Can you please give me a list of thing you need to know so I can look for them?

Comment: I am assuming you need to know the headtube size and type. if its a tapered one or a standard one right?

Comment: Right, you need to know if the steer tube is straight or tapered.  You should be able to tell easily simply by measuring the top and bottom of the head tube.  If both diameters are the same, it should be a straight 1 1/8" steerer.  But since the bike is new, you should just take it to the shop.

Comment: Its a 1 1/8. not tapered.

Comment: Plus Id like to know if I can install a better set of forks like an inverted suspension. Would it be a possible? can I install a 160mm or 200mm fork in my bike or would it be a bad idea?

Comment: @OmerRaja: Installing much longer-travel forks on a bike that came with shorter ones is a bad idea.  It will change the geometry, and probably not for the better.  +/- 20mm might be OK, but you're talking about much more.